# How to decide where to place devices for power quality handeling

Tags: motor, generator, transmission-line, power-engineering, power-quality

In a facility that experienced voltage sags where 175 KVA of the load is sensitive, and we are asked to implement MG set or flywheels to handle the power quality issues. where should the MG set/ flywheel be placed? At transmission line or end user?

Comment: Will the motor-generators always be buffering the sensitive loads?

Comment: So you where tasked with implementing such a system and the best thing you can come up with is asking random people on the interwebs? Sounds like a recipe for Desaster

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am a student, and this is a school assignment. It would be good If you have any book I can refer to

Comment: @amidher: If you ask us to solve your homework, say so clearly.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf yes sir, the assignment states that the industrial facility suffered 20 voltage interruption and sags in the past year. They would like me to study the best way to implement MG set or flywheels to mitigate those faults for optimum result.

Comment: @PlasmaHH its not a homework, its a class project of multiple parts. Asking the community is a part of the learning process. Since I couldn't find the information in my textbook, I thought expert engineers such as yourself could help by either explaining or giving me a source to refer to.

Comment: "not a homework, its a class project" So in other words, it's homework.

Comment: @winny do you have any book or paper I can refer to? It would be helpful if you have, I just want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load regulation is a function of capacity and generator and line resistance, so the shortest path to load is best.

Surge loads demand up to 500% rated load unless using VFD with controlled ramps.

If DCR of load is >10% of GEN line then GEN sags but keeps plant stable until GEN starts to slow down. After which transient start up of load should be stable.

- I estimate Flywheel stored kinetic energy must exceed 8x the surge load energy for 10% dip in plant voltage or 16x for 5%.
- MG set needs a soft start control to also prevent plant dips.